# How to access Mathematica license server (being outside of the local network)

Tags: internet, licensing

This is no *Mathematica*-language specific question but rather a network problem, so if this is the wrong place to ask, I apologize.

I am running *Mathematica* on Windows 7, the license manager `mathlm` is running in a local network. How can I access *Mathematica* when being outside the local network. Is there some tool like license checkout for let's say two hours?

If this is not possible with *Mathematica*, is there some way to forward the ports for license manager via `ssh` and are there problems/restrictions with Windows 7? Btw, contacting the server via `ssh` is possible.

Comment: Ask your organization/university if they have a virtual private network (VPN) set up (many do).  This is a very common way to work around problems like this.  After connection to the VPN it'll appear as if you were on the local network.

Comment: In general, VPN is a reasonable approach, but in this case it won't work. I'm still inside the network of the university (where I could enter via VPN), but as long as I am connected via WIFI, I don't have access to the institute's license server (though I can access it via `ssh`). Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, it is always possible to forward ports using ssh, but I have no experience with license servers, so I don't know what server Mathematica would try to connect to (you have to get it to try to connect to your own machine after forwarding the ports).  There are lots of tutorials on how to forward ports, here's the first one from google: http://www.debianadmin.com/howto-use-ssh-local-and-remote-port-forwarding.html  Sorry I can't help more.  When I tried to use port forwarding to connect to a remote kernel (not license manager), it was always a *lot* of trouble.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to @halirutan and @Szabolcs, I found a working solution by myself. Apparently it won't work with `localhost` on Windows7 but with `127.0.0.1`.

To sum up, I present the ssh-commands, so other users might gain something from this (use your own network names or IPs here):

1. First connect through the firewall via `ssh.server`: `ssh -L 16286:127.0.0.1:16286 user@ssh.server`
2. then forward to another gateway, where you can switch ports again: `ssh -L 16286:mathlm.server:16286 second.gateway.server`

Use either `cygwin` or `putty`, (and make sure, you run them as with sufficient rights -- e.g. as Administrator).

Then you have to enter `!127.0.0.1` in your mathpass file (or enter `127.0.0.1` once *Mathematica* asks you for the license server).

Comment: I'm confused about the second gateway server. This means I need two extra computers apart from the local mathematica-running one and the license server? ssh.server would be the one in the LAN that can access mathlm.server, and then I need to go on to another server, second.gateway.server?

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends where you can tunnel into your network and how your network is configured. Sometimes the first command is sufficient, replacing 127.0.0.1 with your gateway server

Comment: Oh man, thank you! That I've tried out so many combinations that I didn't remember not trying that one... it'll be a while before I can get my mind around what is really what with the ssh forwarding commands.

Answer (score 6):

You question does basically not fit here, but I'm sure it is still one of the best places to ask. I think we shouldn't be too pedantic with the rules. Let me give you some advice, which will unfortunately only help you, if you can cooperate with your admin of the server:

- You have to ensure, that you can reach the license server over an IP, because this is what you will write in the `mathpass` file. If the license-server does run in a local network and has no public IP and you want to access it from anywhere public, I think the usual way will not work.
- You have to ensure, that you can reach the license-server over the port `16286`! Since you can access it over `ssh` it seems this port is not open to the outside world. In our setting at university, the firewall has to know every pc which wants to access the license server.
- You maybe already know, that you then have to use the IP of the license server in your `mathpass` file by entering something similar to

  `!123.123.123.123`

Comment: OK, basically I had all requirements fulfilled, but you gave me the right hint. For port forwarding, I used `localhost` what -- appareantly -- won't work on Windows 7. Instead you have to use `127.0.0.1`. To sum up, I present the `ssh`-commands, so other users might gain something from this:

First connect through the firewall via ssh.server 
`ssh -L 16286:127.0.0.1:16286 user@ssh.server` and then forward to another gateway, where you can switch ports again `ssh -L 16286:mathlm.server:16286 second.gateway.server`. Use either cygwin or putty.