# Command to get License Management Monitor info

Tags: .netlink, monitoring, licensing, resource-management

Using Netlink, when we have more users than *Mathematica* licenses (used in a pool), we get messages such as:

> Error code: 11. Connected MathLink program has closed the link, but there might still be data underway,

that I translate into a more user friendly message.

There's a Wolfram License Management Monitor on a server and it generates these reports:

Ref: http://uczelnia.mazovia.edu.pl/info/mathematica.html
[image]

Unfortunately the License Server is locked down (its still in the network unlike this: [How to access Mathematica license server (being outside of the local network)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15615/how-to-access-mathematica-license-server-being-outside-of-the-local-network)) and I can't install IIS or a Windows Service to retrieve the License Report on demand.

Is there a command that can be used in *Mathematica* (via Netlink or Front-End) to get this information?

#### Update

As per http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/program/monitorlm.html, I can't get this command to work:

```
monitorlm  "servername"
```

Comment: Is that not an executable command? eg here it'd be run from the command line as `/usr/local/math/MathLM800/bin/monitorlm license` (for example)

Comment: Thanks for the comment, in the environment I am working in.. it wont fly, unfortunately my hands are tied. Hence my recommendation is to shell the exe with a script to capture the details.

Comment: You will have to get proper privileges to access mathlm. A license user does (quite probably by design) not have access to the license server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**monitorlm** is an exe that sits on a License Server, its not a Mathematica command.

[image]

Comment: This is perhaps more suited to a comment (sans screenshot)?

Comment: Whats Sans Screenshot? how do I post a image in a comment?

Comment: You don't. As I understand your question,  this is not an answer to it.  Perhaps you can elaborate.